# name 'coding' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to make a game like a clicker, where coding brings money, but I ran into this error. The error seems to be due to the fact that 'coding' is in another function, but I don't understand how I can fix it. Please help me. I will be very grateful to you

```py
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from threading import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox 


button_track = False
button_code = True
wait_code = 30

def check_code():
    global button_code
    if button_code == True:
        money.set(money.get() + 50)
        button_code = False

def buy_klava_func():
    if money.get() >= 50:
        money.set(money.get() - 50)
        buy_klava.grid_remove()
        coding = Button(root, text='Написать код', command=check_code)
        coding.grid(column=0, row=0)

def timer_code():
    global button_code
    global wait_code
    while True:
        if button_code == False:
            coding['state'] = 'disabled'
            sleep(wait_code)
            coding['state'] = 'active'
            button_code = True

root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x900')

money = IntVar()
money.set(50)

buy_klava = Button(root, text='Купить клавиатуру (50 монет)', command=buy_klava_func)
buy_klava.grid(column=0, row=0)

th_timer_code = Thread(target=timer_code)
th_timer_code.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```global coding``` in ```buy_klava_func()```. Coding is not global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `coding` is not a global variable. Declare it above all the functions, so that you can use it within all functions.

```py
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from threading import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox 


button_track = False
button_code = True
wait_code = 30

def check_code():
    global button_code
    if button_code == True:
        money.set(money.get() + 50)
        button_code = False

def buy_klava_func():
    global coding # <=== define coding as global
    if money.get() >= 50:
        money.set(money.get() - 50)
        buy_klava.grid_remove()
        coding = Button(root, text='Написать код', command=check_code)
        coding.grid(column=0, row=0)

def timer_code():
    global button_code
    global wait_code
    global coding
    while True:
        if button_code == False:
            coding['state'] = 'disabled'
            sleep(wait_code)
            coding['state'] = 'active'
            button_code = True

root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x900')

money = IntVar()
money.set(50)

buy_klava = Button(root, text='Купить клавиатуру (50 монет)', command=buy_klava_func)
buy_klava.grid(column=0, row=0)

th_timer_code = Thread(target=timer_code)
th_timer_code.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `coding` is a local variable, so it cannot be accessed inside `timer_code()`.

Since you just replace `buy_klava` by `coding`, my suggestion is simply to configure `buy_klava` instead of removing it and creating `coding`:

```py
def buy_klava_func():
    if money.get() >= 50:
        money.set(money.get() - 50)
        """
        buy_klava.grid_remove()
        coding = Button(root, text='Написать код', command=check_code)
        coding.grid(column=0, row=0)
        """
        # just configure "buy_klava" instead of removing it and create "coding"
        buy_klava.config(text='Написать код', command=check_code)

def timer_code():
    global button_code
    #global wait_code
    while True:
        if button_code == False:
            buy_klava['state'] = 'disabled'  # update buy_klava
            sleep(wait_code)
            buy_klava['state'] = 'active'    # update buy_klava
            button_code = True
```